# Add Row with Sequential Row # in VB.Net DataSet

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to add rows using an "Add Row" Button from Windows Forms and I want to have it add Row number as well but in sequential order. So if the last row # was 9 I want it to add row #10 when I press the button.

I have it set up now so it simply adds a blank row using

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    dt.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

How would I go about making it recognize the order and then create the next row in the sequence

Here is a picture of the design
[image]

Here is the way I fill my datagridview using sql

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Connection String Placeholder")
    Dim Table As New DataTable()
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TrackMain$", connection)
    Adapter.Fill(Table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table

    bind_data()


End Sub
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the code you have already for the `Add Row` button.

Comment: You've not specified your database product, guessing your talking about SQL server here.  Most DB products have some form of AutoInc field type/configuration.  Called Identity in SQL server.  Perhaps look at that and let the DB handle the row numbers.  You could even specify the field type on your Table object although but default these count down from 0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basiclly, you can get the next row number in Form.Load event.

```
Private nextId As Integer = 0
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ...
    bind_data()
    nextId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(0)) + 1
End Sub
```

Then set the row number when adding a new row:

```
Private Sub AddRowBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddRowBtn.Click
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr(0) = nextId
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    nextId += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works as I asked so thank you! However, I have another question if you don't mind. The add row function only adds a +1 to it so is fairly simple and I added a -1 to the delete row piece of code I have. So my question is if I delete say row 12 but I am on row 16 the next add row number will be 15 not row 12 to fill in the blank. How do I go about reordering the rows so that If i delete a row in the middle of a large set of row#'s that it simply reorders itself sequentially again one through the highest number? Sorry for such a long question.